# Is there a way to increase the UIActionSheet pop up speed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am using a simple UIActionSheet in my program:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Miao" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"opt 1",
                            @"opt 2",
                            @"opt 3",
                            @"opt 4",
                            @"opt 5",
                            @"opt 6",
                            @"opt 7",
                            @"opt 8",
                            @"opt 9",
                            nil];


actionSheet.delegate=self;
```

and showing the view using : `[actionSheet showInView:self.view];` Was wondering if there was a way to increase the speed of the popup? It's not that it's lag, would just like it to be faster. Have looked around on the net and can't find anything. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find anything for this in its documentation. Perhaps you should consider creating your own animation for a view with alert.

Comment: Yeah, seem like that's the only way... thanks

Comment: I haven't, but did you try wrapping it in a view animation block?

Comment: UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIActionSheetDelegate is also deprecated.) However you may want to try - showFromRect:inView:animated: and pass NO for the animated property and animate it yourself as it is a subclass of UIView

Answer (score 0):

UIActionSheet can be shown on many ways. Two methods allow you to directly manipulate whether the popup animation should be animated or not:

```
- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or (interesting for iPad):

```
- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Keep in mind that as — @Bamsworld already said — `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS8 and you should use `UIAlertController` instead.